# Sitecore Tab is not appearing after installing sitecore rocks

Tags: sitecore-rocks

I installed

> sitecore rocks from extensions and updates
>    then I restarted my system.

After I checked in VS2017, sitecore tab is not appearing.

Here below I included the installation log file for reference.

```
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - -------------------------------------------
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - 15.9.3041
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - -------------------------------------------
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - Command line parameters:
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\User\Downloads\Sitecore.Rocks.VisualStudio.vsix
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - -------------------------------------------
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
16-02-2019 11:13:20 - -------------------------------------------
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Initializing Install...
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Extension Details...
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Identifier         : V6fb7d81e-c4ff-4b7f-adf4-b04e65155687
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Name               : Sitecore Rocks
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Author             : Sitecore
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Version            : 2.1.126
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Description        : Sitecore Rocks makes Sitecore developers happy.

Directly integrated into Microsoft Visual Studio 2015/2017, Sitecore Rocks provides a fast and streamlined development experience with tools that developers are used to.        
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Locale             : en-US
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   MoreInfoURL        : https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Supported Products : 
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -           Version : [14.0,15.0]
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -           Version : [14.0,15.0]
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -           Version : [14.0,15.0]
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   References         : 
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Prerequisites      : 
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -       -------------------------------------------------------
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -       Name         : Visual Studio core editor
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -       Version      : [15.0.26208.0,16.0)
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Signature Details...
16-02-2019 11:13:22 -   Extension is not signed.
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Searching for applicable products...
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Found installed product - Global Location
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Found installed product - ssms
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.   

16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\Solution\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\ManagedProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\GraphProviderPackage\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\DataDesign\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:22 - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
16-02-2019 11:13:23 - Skipping 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\ExtensionManager\Extensions' as it doesn't exist
16-02-2019 11:13:23 - Skipping 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft SDKs' as it doesn't exist
16-02-2019 11:13:23 - The extension with ID 'V6fb7d81e-c4ff-4b7f-adf4-b04e65155687' is not installed to Visual Studio Community 2017.
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - BEGIN: Processing extension pack
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - END: Processing extension pack
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - Initializing Install...
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - Extension Details...
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Identifier         : V6fb7d81e-c4ff-4b7f-adf4-b04e65155687
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Name               : Sitecore Rocks
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Author             : Sitecore
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Version            : 2.1.126
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Description        : Sitecore Rocks makes Sitecore developers happy.

Directly integrated into Microsoft Visual Studio 2015/2017, Sitecore Rocks provides a fast and streamlined development experience with tools that developers are used to.        
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Locale             : en-US
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   MoreInfoURL        : https://github.com/JakobChristensen/Sitecore.Rocks
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Supported Products : 
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -           Version : [14.0,15.0]
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -           Version : [14.0,15.0]
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -           Version : [14.0,15.0]
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   References         : 
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Prerequisites      : 
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -       -------------------------------------------------------
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -       Name         : Visual Studio core editor
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -       Version      : [15.0.26208.0,16.0)
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - Signature Details...
16-02-2019 11:13:26 -   Extension is not signed.
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - Searching for applicable products...
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - Found installed product - Global Location
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - Found installed product - ssms
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
16-02-2019 11:13:26 - The extension with ID 'V6fb7d81e-c4ff-4b7f-adf4-b04e65155687' is not installed to Visual Studio Community 2017.
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - InstallProgressPage ChangeType: 'SingleInstall' operationCount: '2' Text: 'Installing Sitecore Rocks...'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - The following target products have been selected...
16-02-2019 11:13:33 -   Visual Studio Community 2017
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - 
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\zq2obtwo.o1j\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\zmvnuj3n.cyw\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\zizq1sfm.ptb\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\ywq5o2i5.ryf\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\yjrei1nc.kes\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\x3spxubm.iy1\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\wsip5iun.qnf\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TestWindow.Dotnet\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TestPlatform\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\qub3c4ok.v1v\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\o3rkgae4.ems\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\neoyltg4.bmz\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools Diagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\RemoteDebugger2.2CTP\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\RemoteDebugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools\Common\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools Azure\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\Shared\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web Tools\Library Manager\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WCF Connected Service\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\14.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\12.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\11.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Visual Studio MPF\10.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Unit Test Explorer\TestWIExtension\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TemplateEngine\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\SQLEditor\Vsix\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\SQLDB\Vsix\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\SQLDB\SSDTUpdate\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Publish\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Portable Library Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Modeling\15.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Microsoft Office 365 Connected Service\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedProjectSystem\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodeSense\Framework\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Microsoft\.NetNative\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\kzmqwvys.iuq\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\knw2g3bc.hyz\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\jixjdf4u.nps\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\ifcnfrm5.na3\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\hdqg42bz.ck3\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\fzb104b4.fzt\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\fldfgssw.v3t\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\fkpwklwm.vn4\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\eljob5zl.bhj\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\chvzxqpj.w4y\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\atfm2vvn.3hs\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\anvcgh0c.i33\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\55chhtd2.1tv\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\41t33m3p.xqm\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3npakkoh.yf1\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3dirqi3p.qqy\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\2eu3u23k.sgm\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\1voqhn4b.ji3\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0104n003.i2v\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:33 - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Visual Studio MPF\15.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\TreeNavigation\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\TreeNavigation\GraphProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Shell\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\PerfMarkers\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\ParallelDebugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\NavigateTo\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\NavigateTo\FileProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\DotNetObjectAlloc\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\DiagnosticsHub\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\Debugger\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Platform\CPUSampling\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\XamlLanguageService\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\XamlDiagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Language Service\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\WebDiagnosticsAttach\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ToolWindows\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\EdgeDebugAdapter\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\WebClient\Diagnostics\ChromeDebugAdapter\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Razor\v3.0\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\Exports\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Web\ASPX\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Editors\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TypeScript\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TextMate\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TestWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TemplateProviders\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ReferenceManager\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\RazorLanguageServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProjectServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Project\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ProductUpdate\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Performance Tools\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\OpenFolder\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\NuGet\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\SourceBasedTestDiscovery\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\LanguageServices\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\InteractiveComponents\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\ExpressionEvaluators\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\LanguageServer\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Language\GenerateType\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Language\CallHierarchy\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\InteractiveWindow\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\GettingStartedTemplates\Resources\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\FSharp\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ExtensionManager\ServiceModule\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ErrorList\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Editorconfig\Wizard\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Editor\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Diff\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\DesignTools\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodingConventions\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ClientDiagnostics\AppResponsiveness\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\ASP.NET Core\UserSecrets\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\Solution\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\Providers\ManagedProvider\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\Microsoft\Architecture Tools\GraphProviderPackage\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\DataDesign\extension.vsixmanifest'
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Skipping 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\ExtensionManager\Extensions' as it doesn't exist
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Skipping 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft SDKs' as it doesn't exist
16-02-2019 11:13:34 - Beginning to install extension to Visual Studio Community 2017...
16-02-2019 11:13:36 - Install to Visual Studio Community 2017 completed successfully. The extension has been installed to C:\USERS\USER\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\15.0_C2D19173\EXTENSIONS\K3KERKPG.H3D\
16-02-2019 11:13:36 - Failure encountered during /updateConfiguration step. Ignoring failure and considering requested operation a success.

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The requested operation requires elevation
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.EngineUtilities.<RunUpdateConfigurationAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at VSIXInstaller.Utilities.<RunUpdateConfiguration>d__8.MoveNext()
```

Comment: You get an error at the end regarding elevation. Did you run the install as an admin? If not, try that..

Comment: i installed from Extensions and updates from VS.
Note:i VS is running as administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

- uninstall Rocks
- delete C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_c2d19173\privateregistry.bin and privateregistry.user.bin file (please backup them first)
- reinstall Rocks
- start Visual Studio and problem should be solved